# How to deserialize JSON Array to Apache beam PCollection<javaObject>

Tags: java, apache-beam, json-deserialization

I have data like

```
[{"ProjectId":1476401625,"ProjectName":"This is project name","ProjectPostcode":4178},{"ProjectId":2343,"ProjectName":"This is project 2 name","ProjectPostcode":5323}]
```

I need to to deserialize it to Java object and I use this code :

```
PCollection<Project> deserialisedProjectObject = projectFile.apply("Deserialize Projects", ParseJsons.of(Project.class))
        .setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Project.class));
```

but I always got error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse a com.lendlease.dp.entity.Project from JSON value: [{"ProjectId":1476401625,"ProjectName":"This is project name","ProjectPostcode":4178},{"ProjectId":2343,"ProjectName":"This is project 2 name","ProjectPostcode":5323}]
```

If I change the code to become :

```
PCollection<Project[]> deserialisedProjectObject = projectFile.apply("Deserialize Projects", ParseJsons.of(Project[].class))
        .setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Project[].class));
```

The runner able to deserialize it but I need this line to return a collection of Project; not collection of Project array

Comment: really hard to read it without proper formatting,
You can use ``` ``` for json. This way you would have mach more attention to your question

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with a Project[] object, so the parse is correct. To extract the Project objects from that object, just apply a FlatMap transform after the ParseJson, outputting the elements within the Array.

As well as ParseJson you may want to look at:

[JsonToRow](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.24.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/JsonToRow.html)

The output of this is a Row object which you can use as a [schema](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#what-is-a-schema) which provide a lot of nice functionality, see [using schemas](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#using-schemas). If you need a an actual POJO within the pipeline as well as the Row object you can make use of [Convert.fromRow](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.24.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/transforms/Convert.html) to turn it into a Pojo object.